# looking for way show all unique code based on day index

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to show how many unique characters on that day based on a day in one column, for example, on day 01 we have code DC13850-DC13873 , when I input the formula with day 01 I want all codes in that day to show, and also when I change the day all the code also change based on the selected day
:

```
day Code
01  DC13850
01  DC13851
01  DC13852
02  DC13853
02  DC13854
02  DC13855
03  DC13856
03  DC13857
03  DC13858
```

I've been struggling with it, can anyone help me?

[image: data example]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(E:E; D:D="01"))
```